# Nose Test Generators inside Class

Tags: python, generator, nose

Is it possible to run nose test generators inside custom classes? I am trying to convert the [example](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.1/writing_tests.html#test-generators) into a simple class based version:

```
file: trial.py
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
class ATest():
    def test_evens(self):
        for i in range(0, 5):
            yield self.check_even, i, i * 3

    def check_even(self, n, nn):
        assert n % 2 == 0 or nn % 2 == 0
```

That results in

```
$ nosetests -v trial.py
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

I had a look through the changelog and believe that this should work since version [0.9.0a1](https://code.google.com/p/python-nose/source/browse/CHANGELOG?name=0.9#169).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The solution is the less expected one: do *NOT subclass from `unittest.TestCase`* in order to have nosetests discover the generator method. Code working with nosetests 1.1.3 (latest from GitHub):

```
class TestA(object):
    def test_evens(self):
        for i in range(0, 5):
            yield self.check_even, i, i * 3

    def check_even(self, n, nn):
        assert n % 2 == 0 or nn % 2 == 0
```

Also, use `TestA` instead of `ATest`.

```
test.py:2: TestA.test_evens[0] PASSED
test.py:2: TestA.test_evens[1] FAILED
test.py:2: TestA.test_evens[2] PASSED
test.py:2: TestA.test_evens[3] FAILED
test.py:2: TestA.test_evens[4] PASSED
```

Comment: That sucks; it'd be nice to be able to use unittest's assertRaisesRegexp for this :/

Comment: @ChrisR: You can use `nose.tools.assert_raises_regexp`

Comment: To add on to this answer, nose now documents this behavior. "Please note that method generators are not supported in unittest.TestCase subclasses." http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html

Answer (score -7):

I believe you have to subclass unittest.TestCase

```
import unittest

class ATest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_evens(self):
        for i in range(0, 5):
            yield self.check_even, i, i * 3

    def check_even(self, n, nn):
        assert n % 2 == 0 or nn % 2 == 0
```

Comment: See Andrés' answer — `nose` cannot run generator tests when the method creating them belongs to a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`.

Comment: if you are considering subclassing TestCase classes dont, they are not designed for subclassing and you see differences in behaviour between test runners.

Comment: From the Python docs : "To make your own test cases you must write subclasses of TestCase" - the documentation specifically states that TestCase is designed to be subclassed  - "This class is intended to be used as a base class, with specific tests being implemented by concrete subclasses.", so the assertion that it isn't seems a bit odd.